# remove space after newpage

Tags: indentation

In this article:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
a
\newpage
b
\\c
\end{document}
```

b is spaced weirdly.
\raggedbottom didn't help
How can i fix it and slap it on the left?

Comment: b is placed where it is expected, if you find that weird you need to say where you expected it to be placed, we can not read your mind.

Comment: unrelated to the `\newpage`  a and b are indented as they start a paragraph, is that what you are asking about?

Comment: `\newpage` first ends the current paragraph, then fills up the current page with white space and goes to the next page, so `\raggedbottom` is not involved (by the way, it is the default in `article`). In your case “b” is indented, because it starts a new paragraph.

Comment: do you want all paragraphs to be unindented (add `\usepackage{parskip}` but the vast majority of publications over the centuries of typeset documents use paragraph indentation)

Comment: I want b and c to be at the same x_position.

Comment: yes but just them or the whole document? how do you want the reader to know a paragraph has started? in particular a is at the same position as b do you want to change that as well?

Comment: See also `\pagebreak`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position is not related to the newpage, it is simply standard paragraph indentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
a

b\\
c
\end{document}
```

If you would prefer to mark paragraphs with no indentation and vertical space instead (which is more common in digital output than print) you could add `\usepackage{parskip}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
a

b\\
c
\end{document}
```